# Admin-on-Rest Is there a way to get rid of duplicates in ReferenceInput for Filters?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am running into an issue where I am trying to filter on a column called "Severity", there are duplicates within the column. This column contains ERROR, INFO, or DEBUG. When I use this:

```
const LogFilter = (props) => (
     <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
        <ReferenceInput label="Severity" source="severity" reference="archivedfiles" allowEmpty>
            <SelectInput optionText="Severity" />
        </ReferenceInput>
     </Filter>
);
```

In my drop down I get a list of tons of things repeated... Is there a way to make it have only the options I want with no duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a HigherOrder component to wrap the SelectInput and filter things out before they hit the select input.

```
const SelectUniqueChoices = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const filteredChoices = UniqueElements(props.choices)
  const newProps = {...props}
  newProps.choices = filteredChoices 
  return (<WrappedComponent {...newProps} />)
}

const UniqueElements = (array) => (
   Array.from(new Set(array))
)

const WrappedSelectField = SelectUniqueChoices(SelectInput)

const LogFilter = (props) => (
     <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
        <ReferenceInput label="Severity" source="severity" reference="archivedfiles" allowEmpty>
            <WrappedSelectField optionText="Severity" />
        </ReferenceInput>
     </Filter>
);
```

Comment: Got it to work based off of what you said changed it like so.
`function MyFilter(array){
    var filterarray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            if (i === 0 )
                {
                    filterarray.push(array[i]);
                }
            else if (array[i].job !== array[i-1].job)
                {
                    filterarray.push(array[i]);
                }
        }
return filterarray;
}

const UniqueElements = (array) => (
    MyFilter(array)
)`

Comment: Looks good! Set is a cool new concept in ES6 worth checking out sometime.